# Selecting from one dataframe using values from a second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, selection, mask

I have two dataframes with the same index and columns:

```
In: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [ random.random(), random.random(), random.random()],
                   'B' : [ random.random(), random.random(), random.random()],
                   'C' : [ random.random(), random.random(), random.random()]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)],
                   'B' : [random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)],
                   'C' : [random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)]})


df1
Out:
    A   B   C
0   0.424566    0.054485    0.830993
1   0.673692    0.754941    0.621544
2   0.890594    0.805776    0.878123
In: df2
Out:

    A   B   C
0   9   9   3
1   4   6   6
2   10  2   9
```

I want to select values from `df1` depending on the corresponding value in `df2` and return it as an array.

e.g. selecting by the value `6` in the example above would return `[0.754941, 0.621544]`

I have looked at `mask` but can't see how to apply a mask from one df to the second df.

Comment: How about `df1[df2==6]`?

Comment: Use `df1.values[df2.eq(6)]` to get your desired array.

Answer (score 4):

If same index and columns in both DataFrmes, is possible use indexing with mask from `df2` with `2d array` created by `to_numpy` or `values`:

```
#pandas 0.24+
a = df1.to_numpy()[df2 == 6]
#oldier pandas versions
#a = df1.values[df2 == 6]
print (a)
[0.754941 0.621544]
```